# Compute module 3 versus compute module 3 lite difference

Tags: compute-module, adafruit

I want to buy Compute module 3 and from looking at the description the difference between CM3 and CM3 Lite is that the Lite version doesn't have on board SD card.

So if I buy the lite version I can plug in a SD card with Rasbian into the IO board to get it to work?  Can anyone confirm if I'm right and this is only difference?